# Override files from dependent deb package

Tags: ubuntu, dependencies, deb

I try to build a `deb` package that serves specific configuration files for SSH (i.e. `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`). I'd also like to depend my package to upstream `openssh-client` package, to achieve installation of *openssh-client* and "on-top" installation if my specific configuration file when calling `apt-get install my-ssh-package`.

I use *fpm*/*fpm-cookery* for building my *deb* package. This works but when I do a local test using *dpkg*, I receive that error:

```
$ dpkg -i pkg/my-ssh-package_0.1.0-1_all.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package my-ssh-package.
(Reading database ... 18814 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../my-ssh-package_0.1.0-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking my-ssh-package (0.1.0-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive pkg/my-ssh-package_0.1.0-1_all.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/etc/ssh/ssh_config', which is also in package openssh-client 1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2.3
Errors were encountered while processing:
 pkg/my-ssh-package_0.1.0-1_all.deb
```

How could I force my package to override the `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` coming from upstream *openssh-client* package?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make your package install your new /etc/ssh/ssh_config in /tmp
2. Add a *postinst* file in your package that copy the file from /tmp to /etc/ssh